# How to get the jQuery methods on Node.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Using `Object.keys($.fn)` (or `Object.keys(jQuery.fn)`) on the client side works fine to get the jQuery functions as array.

How can I use the [`jquery` package from `npm`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery) to  get the same array?

I tried:

- `require("jquery").fn` **`=>`** `undefined` (since we have to initialize it providing the window object)
- I tried to initialize the jQuery function like this:

  ```
  var $ = require("jquery")({
      // Simulate the document object
      document: {
          createElement: function () {
              return {
                  parentNode: {
                      removeChild: function () {

                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  });
  ```

  Running it this way I get this error:

  ```
  /home/...node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:897
  var div = document.createElement("div");
                    ^

  TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined
  ```

So, basically, I don't really want to *use* jQuery in Node.js but just to get the array of jQuery methods (like on the client), avoiding to hardcode it in the code.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why? What would you be doing on the backend with jQuery?

Comment: jQuery is made for DOM manipulation which is made for the frontend. Node.js is for backend and there is no DOM as I know.

Comment: _jQuery is a fast, small, and feature-rich JavaScript library. It makes things like HTML document traversal and manipulation, event handling, animation, and Ajax much simpler with an easy-to-use API that works across a multitude of browsers._

Comment: Why do you want a list of jQuery methods on the server? What do you plan on doing with them?

Comment: You can have something like jQuery on Node.js side with  [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio). I've used Cheerio in one of my projects and I have had success.

Comment: I do know know what jQuery is and I do know what Node.js is. What I want is to get the jQuery method names and do something with them on the server (just with the names). I believe, the good way is not to hardcode them but to get them using the `jquery` package.

Comment: @danilodeveloper I don't want to generate/modify html on the server (I did use `cheerio` in some of my projects), but what I want is exactly the jQuery method names as array.

Comment: I would think your code might read `var div = $.document.createElement("div");`

Comment: @mplungjan I followed [this comment from jQuery code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/99e8ff1baa7ae341e94bb89c3e84570c7c3ad9ea/src/intro.js#L18-L24) to initialize the jQuery function on the server side.

Comment: Another option would be to reference the xml documents for api.jquery.com (can be found on github)

Comment: To all that are wondering what mad science can I do with this list: https://github.com/IonicaBizau/phantom-jquery :-) I coded a library to include jQuery in the Phantom page and make it easily accessible. For now I just stored the methods and fields in [this list](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/phantom-jquery/blob/765f00ed481d09f8909ed895915b9415c1c7556a/lib/jQuery-methods.js#L2).

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom, it provides a partial implementation of the DOM, especially for use in node, and even allows you to load jquery dynamically inside the mock window. Something like this:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");

jsdom.env(
  '<p></p>',
  ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
  function (err, window) {
    console.log(Object.keys(window.$.fn));
  }
);
```

Comment: Hmm, but that's really bad from the performance view. Isn't it possible to use the `jquery` package just to get all the `$.fn` fields?

Comment: @IonicăBizău nope. not unless you can somehow modify it before requiring it (good luck)

Comment: ATM there's no alternative. In non-browser CommonJS environments jQuery exposes a simple factory function, which you need to invoke and pass a "window" object to. The jQuery prototype itself is encapsulated and inaccessible. You could create a PR and hang the prototype as a property of the factory function to allow access.

Answer (score 0):

There are static methods and Instance methods in Jquery, do probably you want to have both, and clone them with Object.assign().

You should try to iterate over both of them like :

```
var jsdom=require('jsdom').jsdom;
var document = jsdom("hello world");
var window = document.defaultView;

var jQuery=require('jquery')(window);


var clonedInstanceMethods = {};
for (var instancemethod in jQuery.prototype){
    Object.assign(clonedInstanceMethods,jQuery.prototype[instancemethod])
}

console.log(clonedInstanceMethods);
```

now do the same with the static methods ... something like that. you get the picture.

We use jsdom to create a window.
should work now.

Comment: Problem is that when you `require("jquery")` in Node, it doesn't return the jQuery function you know on the client but it returns a function that you need to use to initialize the jQuery: `require("jquery")(window)`...

Comment: Thanks, I'm still waiting for a better alternative. `jsdom` is really big library from what I know.